# how to develop AForge.NET for Computer Vision

Tags: c#, gesture-recognition, aforge

I'm trying to develop a program to recognize a hand gestures and base on the hand gestures, run some commands or move the mouse. how can I use AForge.NET with C#??? it is possible to do that? is there any tutorial out there???? Please help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/audio-video/Motion_Detection.aspx)  is an article by the author of AForge.NET, although it is not about gesture detection

Answer (score 2):

A gesture sample on [codeproject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/directx/lasergesture.aspx) (not using AForge.NET) or [another sample](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/Webcam_Tic_Tac_Toe.aspx) (this time using AForge.NET) showing how to uset the library. Hope it helps.